# SignalR group registration server methods not being hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I've followed this guide, [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide (How to manage group membership from the Hub class)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#groupsfromhub) and yet am unable to get my server side `ShipmentHub` methods to execute.

My `ShipmentHub` class looks like this:

```
public class ShipmentHub : Hub
{
    IShipmentLogic shipmentLogic;

    public ShipmentHub(IShipmentLogic shipmentLogic)
    {
        this.shipmentLogic = shipmentLogic;
    }

    public void CreateShipment(IEnumerable<Shipment> shipments)
    {
        // Clients.All.createShipment(shipments.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate));
        Clients.Group(shipments.FirstOrDefault().ShipmentId)
               .createShipment(shipments.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate));
    }

    public async Task WatchShipmentId(string shipmentId)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, shipmentId);
        Clients.Group(shipmentId).createShipment(shipmentLogic.Get(shipmentId, true));
    }

    public Task StopWatchingShipmentId(string shipmentId)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, shipmentId);
    }
}
```

My client, more or less, looks like this:

```
var shipmentHub = $.connection.shipmentHub;
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start();

var shipmentId = "SHP-W-GE-100122";
        
if (previousShipmentId) {
    shipmentHub.server.stopWatchingShipmentId(previousShipmentId);
}

if (shipmentId.length) {
    previousShipmentId = shipmentId;
    shipmentHub.server.watchShipmentId(shipmentId);
}
```

In the SignalR client logs I see that these are being called:

> SignalR: Invoking shipmenthub.WatchShipmentId
>
> SignalR: Invoking shipmenthub.StopWatchingShipmentId
>
> SignalR: Invoking shipmenthub.WatchShipmentId

And, aside from just the logs, these methods *are* being hit:

```
proxies['shipmentHub'].server = {
    createShipment: function (shipments) {
        return proxies['shipmentHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['shipmentHub'], $.merge(["CreateShipment"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
     },

    stopWatchingShipmentId: function (shipmentId) {
        return proxies['shipmentHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['shipmentHub'], $.merge(["StopWatchingShipmentId"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
     },

    watchShipmentId: function (shipmentId) {
        return proxies['shipmentHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['shipmentHub'], $.merge(["WatchShipmentId"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
     }
};
```

And, as a final note, before I added the `Watch` and `StopWatching` methods, everything else worked (i.e., `CreateShipment` would call the `Client.All.createShipment` method without issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the parameterized constructor in `ShipmentHub`.  According to [Dependency Injection in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection):

> *By default, SignalR expects a hub class to have a parameterless constructor. However, you can easily register a function to create hub instances, and use this function to perform DI. Register the function by calling GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register.*

So, you need to modify your `Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method to resolve the dependency for you:

```
GlobalHost
    .DependencyResolver
    .Register(
        typeof(ShipmentHub), 
           () => new ShipmentHub(new ShipmentLogic()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the connection to the server to be established before you can start calling methods on the server from the client. hub.start() returns a promise, here is the basic pattern for doing something once that promise is resolved.

```
 var shipmentHub = $.connection.shipmentHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(talkToServer);

    var talkToServer=function(){
    var shipmentId = "SHP-W-GE-100122";
        if (previousShipmentId) {
            shipmentHub.server.stopWatchingShipmentId(previousShipmentId);
        }

        if (shipmentId.length) {
            previousShipmentId = shipmentId;
            shipmentHub.server.watchShipmentId(shipmentId);
        }
}
```

Comment: Same issue.  This is in an `eventListener` to an inputs blur event.  I moved the registration of that `eventListener` to the `done` promise and still can't hit the methods on the server.  That is, `$.connection.hub.start().done(function() { theInput.addEventListener('blur', function(evt) { // do stuff }) });`